# Using cell reference to get search string for .find in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code to find a mail by subject and work with that. When I am putting the exact subject line as string in myItems.Find, it works fine. But if I put the exact same thing in an excel sheet and try to run the code with cell reference its throwing error(Run-time error '-2147352567). Please help me out.
    Thanks in advance.

```
Sub SearchMail()
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim sentbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ForwardMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set sentbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set myItems = sentbox.Items

    'This Works!!
    'Set mail = myItems.Find("[Subject] = ""Exact Search text""")


    Workbooks("Outlook Mail.xlsm").Sheets("MailingList").Activate
    Sheets("MailingList").Select

    'This doesn't. Why??
    Set mail = myItems.Find("[Subject] = Cells(17,11).Value")

    Set ForwardMail = mail.ReplyAll
    ForwardMail.Display
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put it in quotes, it becomes a string. try this:

```
Set mail = myItems.Find("[Subject] = " & Cells(17,11).Value)
```

Although I would advice that you don't use just `Cell`. Late bind your sheet and then use it:

```
Set mail = myItems.Find("[Subject] = """ & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MailingList").Cells(17,11).Value) & """"
```

This way you don't have to select the sheet either

Comment: Hi @Zac , Trying this I'm getting Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set. What's going wrong?

Comment: Which statement are you using? first or the second? also, can you check the value in debug mode for the cell?

Comment: I think it was missing quotes. I've updated the second statement. Try that (sorry I can't test this)

Comment: Hi Zac, I used the second statement and it works now. Thank you so much for your valuable input.

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped